# Overwrite the ancient OSX builtin version of tidy

Tags: macos, homebrew, htmltidy

So I've got OSX Mavericks and I want to use the Sublimelinter for HTML5, however the built in OSX tidy is some old 2006 package. I did some surfing and figured out I had to just

```
$ brew install --HEAD tidy
```

that all said and done. I also did the linking:

```
$ brew unlink tidy && brew link tidy
```

but I'm still getting HTML linting errors for my HTML5 code.

```
$ tidy -v
HTML Tidy for Mac OS X released on 31 October 2006 - Apple Inc. build 15.12
```

I don't see what I'm doing wrong here, I figured the unlinking and linking would overwrite the OSX tidy version with the newer homebrew one.

Comment: Make sure that the brew tidy is actually used by Sublime (thus, its path is in the `$PATH` variable of sublime and _before_ the OS X default one. Probably the OS X `$PATH` was adjusted by homebrew, but not Sublime's one.

Comment: ah that's all, I was in the understanding that it should overwrite the OSX tidy. Thank you sir

Comment: I was just writing about reposting the guess as an answer, but you found it faster than I could write another comment about it. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the brew `tidy` is actually used by Sublime (thus, its path is in the `$PATH` variable of sublime and before the OS X default one (which is located in `/usr/bin`).

Probably the OS X (let's better say bash) `$PATH` was adjusted by homebrew, but not Sublime's one.